# Scala: Convert a Sealed Trait instance to an HList

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless

Consider the following:

```
sealed trait baseData {
  def weight: Int
  def priority: Int
} 

case class data1(override val weight: Int, override val priority: Int) extends baseData
```

How would I define a function with the following signature that transforms `data1` into an HList?

```
def toHlist[A <: baseData] (data: A) = {}
```

I want to pass in a trait instance into the `toHlist` function instead of the actual case class because there will be more than one case class extending the trait. I also don't want to hardcode any fields; I'm looking for a totally generic solution.

I'm sure this is doable with the [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0) library, but haven't been able to figure out how.

**EDIT**

`toHList` needs to be able to handle a `baseData` pointer to a case class instance, as so:

```
val data: baseData = data1(1,2)
toHlist(data)
```

The reason for this is that we will have more than one case class extending `baseData`, and we will now know which one to pass to `toHlist` until run time.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the final answer, but it will help you refine your question,

```
scala> def toHlist[A <: baseData](data: A)(implicit gen: Generic[A]): gen.Repr = gen.to(data)
toHlist: [A <: baseData](data: A)(implicit gen: shapeless.Generic[A])gen.Repr

scala> toHlist(data1(23, 13))
res0: shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.HNil]] = 23 :: 13 :: HNil
```

Comment: Thanks! This works with `toHlist(data1(23, 13))`, but won't if we all we have is a pointer to the base trait: `val data: baseData = data1(23,13)`, `toHlist(data)`. In my case, I won't know which case class to pass in until runtime. Any ideas there?

Comment: Could you update your question in the light of the above?

Comment: See above. Thanks!